# Select control binding doesn't working in Angular 8

Tags: angular, select, binding, angular-material, angular8

After check few replies, I'm here to make this question because I'm having some troubles with the binding of an "mat-select" input.

this is the code in the component.ts file

```
  selectedIndustry : any;  
  constructor(private industrysectorService: IndustrySectorService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.industrysectorService.get().subscribe((response: IResponse<IIndustrySector[]>) => {
      if (response.isSuccessful) {
        this.industries = response.result.list;        
      } else {
        this.industries = [];        
      }
    });

    this.selectedIndustry = this.industries[0];
```

and this in the componente.html file.

```
<mat-label>Industry Sector</mat-label>
      <mat-select required type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedIndustry" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <option *ngFor="let industry of industries" [ngValue]="industry.id">{{industry.industrySectorName}}</option>   
    </mat-select>
```

the error message in the console is:

```
EngagementDetailsComponent.html:43 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute
at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
at setUpControl (forms.js:3181)
at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7102)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31906)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EngagementDetailsComponent.html:48)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
```

and the data bingind doesn't work.
the variables: "selectedIndustry" and "industries" was filled correctly from the DB.
I checked [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kzu8w) example but i can't figurate where is the issue.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `mat-select` and normal select. Please use `mat-option` with `[value]` attribute binding instead. [More Info](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples)

```
<mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food">
      {{food}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Comment: Than you Joseph! besides what you told me, the right property is [value]="industry.id"  . I can fixit with you reply! thanks a lot!